# Error with publishing Sort tool on ArcGIS Server 10

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcpy, arcgis-server, geoprocessing-service

I have a model that has one tool (Sort), works fine on desktop. When I try to publish get this error.

```
 Geoprocessing service initialization failed.
Invalid parameter: Tool - General Sort : Parameter - Field(s) : Data Type - Value Table
```

Turns out this data type is not supported, looking for a workaround that would allow users to choose more than one values for Sort field. Thanks, Jay

Comment: This may or may not be relevant but I think Sort tool needs ArcInfo/Advanced license which I think means you'll need ArcGIS Server Advanced to publish a model that uses it.  Are you using ArcGIS Server Standard or Advanced?

Comment: I am using ArcGIS Server Advanced Enterprise, this issue is more related to support of Value table data type in Server, I am looking for a workaround for this limitation. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are some workarounds for using the Value Table data type with a Geoprocessing Service documented under **[Input modes and parameter data types](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0154000003mn000000)** (under the heading **Value Tables**).  Unfortunately, Sort is not mentioned as one of them but the Intersect and Dissolve examples may give you some ideas.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're just asking for a table of information through a GP task?  If so then there are more efficient ways of doing it, like using the Query Method against the map service.  If so then there's no need to sort in the Python.  You do it on the web-service instead if you look here:

http://[host]/arcgis/rest/services/[folder]/[service]/MapServer/0/query

there is an "Order By Fields:" parameter, you put the field names here and your the response to your request will be sorted appropriately.